# AnimatedVisibility doesn't work in Canvas

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

When I use `AnimatedVisibility` around `Canvas`, it doesn't work.

```
AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = firstShowVisible,
    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
    enter = fadeIn(0f, tween(300, 3100, LinearEasing))
) {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier) {
        drawCircleBackground(color, radius, strokeWidth)
        drawCircleProgress(color, progress, radius, strokeWidth)
    }
}
```

The Canvas item would show immediately, rather than fade in slowly.

And firstShowVisible is changed by

```
var firstShowVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
LaunchedEffect(true) {
    firstShowVisible = true
}
```

It works for other items, cannot work for Canvas only to me

Comment: And how do you change `firstShowVisible`? [this](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/c7287f11dcc239ee100327857bd9b0ad) animates fine to me

Comment: @PhilipDukhov same way with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.
It's because the arc I draw is not in the area of the outer Box.
When I make the outer Box fillMaxSize, it works.